# How to set default username for MANIFEST.MF for my computer?

Tags: maven, manifest.mf

I'm looking for a way to set the "built by" entry in my `MANIFEST.MF` to something different from my user name. I can do it at build time with `-Duser.name=<whatIwant>` but I'd like to have it default to something besides my system user name. I do not want to do it in my project either, as we work in a group and I'm sure everyone does not want to be me.

I have also attempted to set it in my `.m2/settings.xml` but for some reason I cannot get it to read correctly. I've created a profile, named work, with `<properties><user.name>whatIWant</user.name></properties>` but it still used the system name (and yes, I remember to set work to always be active).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set it like this:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            ...
                <manifestEntries>
                        <Built-By>${your.builtby.variable}</Built-By>
                </manifestEntries>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
        ...
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem here (add system properties in setting.xml does not work) but the bottom line is I cannot update the pom.xml file, so above answer does not work for me.

Very simple solution is to add this variable to JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS system environment. For any java command, this variable will be included.

Linux

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Duser.name=whatIWant"
```

Window

```
set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Duser.name=whatIWant"
```

You may want to set this permanently (in .bashrc or window system env)

Hope this help for others.